# ¿Porqué mi footer no ocupa todo el ancho de la pantalla?

Tags: css, bootstrap

El  no ocupa todo el ancho de la página ya que siempre queda con un margen a la izquierda.

En  quité todos los márgenes y revisé todos los , pero de todos modos no logro quitar ese margen. Espero que me puedan ayudar. Muchas Gracias!!

Se ve de esta manera:

```css
body{
   margin: 0%;
   padding: 0%;
   
   
}

#banner{
    padding-top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}


a{
    color: black;
}

#nav-header{
    background-color: rgba(199, 210, 214, 0.692);

   
}

#navbar-toggler{
    
    background-color: rgba(206, 206, 206, 0.692);
    padding: 3px, 4px, 3px 4px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(151, 151, 151);    

}

#btn-menu{
    padding: 3px, 4px, 3px 4px;
    width: 30px;
    margin-top: 1px;
   
}

#logo-header{
    
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 130px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

img{
   
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    max-width: 100%;
   
    
}


.title{
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

#home-card{
    text-align: start;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    
}

#line-home{
    background-color: rgba(3, 158, 197, 0.932);
}

.footerContainer{
    background-color: rgb(36, 39, 44);
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgb(214, 214, 214);
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100vw;
    text-align: justify;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
    position:absolute;
    left:-0%;
    
  
    

    
    
}

#line-footer{
    background-color: rgb(136, 136, 136);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />

    <title>XREF</title>

    <!-- CSS de Bootstrap -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <!-- CSS Font Awesome -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <!-- CSS Google Fonts -->
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,300"
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
    />

    <!-- CSS Propio -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav id="nav-header" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a id="logo-header" class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
          <img src="img/Logo-PNG.png" alt="Logo xref" />
        </a>

        <button
          id="navbar-toggler"
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#navbarLinks"
          aria-controls="navbarLinks"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span id="btn-menu" class="btn-block">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
          </span>
        </button>
        <div
          id="navbarLinks"
          class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end"
        >
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Inicio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="nosotros.html">Nosotros</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="servicios.html">Servicios</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="contacto.html">Contacto</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="banner">
      <img src="img/Banner.jpg" alt="Banner XREF" />
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>Bienvenido</h1>
      </div>

      <hr id="line-home" />

      <div id="home-card">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h4>Nosotros</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                  the bulk of the card's content.
                </p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Ver Más</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h4>Servicios</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                  the bulk of the card's content.
                </p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Ver Más</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h4>Proyectos</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                  the bulk of the card's content.
                </p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Ver Más</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <footer class="footerContainer ">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <h6>XREF</h6>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <p>
              <i class="far fa-envelope-open"></i> xrefarquitectura@gmail.com
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <p><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i> 098 436 244</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <p><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i> Xref</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr id="line-footer" />
        <div class="row">
          <div id="" class="col-md-3">
            <p style="color: #ddd">&copy; XREF 2020</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- JS de Popper.js -->
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- JS de Bootstrap -->
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- JS de Vue.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

    <!-- JS Propio -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

El `<footer>` no ocupa todo el ancho de la página ya que siempre queda con un margen a la izquierda.

En `<body>` quité todos los márgenes y revisé todos los `<div>`, pero de todos modos no logro quitar ese margen. Espero que me puedan ayudar.
Muchas Gracias!!

Se ve de esta manera:

[image: Screenshot de la página web]

Y este es el código:

```css
#footer{
    background-color: rgb(36, 39, 44);
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgb(214, 214, 214);
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100vw;
    text-align: justify;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#line-footer{
    background-color: rgb(136, 136, 136);
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h6>XREF</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
          <p><i class="far fa-envelope-open"></i> xrefarquitectura@gmail.com</p>
       </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <p><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i> 098 436 244</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <p><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i> Xref</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr id="line-footer">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="" class="col-md-3 ">
        <p style="color: #ddd;"> &copy; XREF 2020</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Por favor lee [ask] y de paso checa el [tour], considera editar y mostrar un [mcve] desde el cual podamos reproducir el *fallo* y en concencuencia ayudar.

Comment: Por que no hay código HTML o CSS mostrado, entonces no podemos ver que pasa.

Comment: Bien no me habia dado cuenta, ahí lo agregue

Comment: @user206022 ahora explícame por que tu `body` tiene un `margin` de 8px ??? Además, no está todo el código, veo de inmediato que faltan divs y otros contenedores que no se ven en tu muestra

Comment: una cosa que pasa es que si esta dentro del contenedor aunque tome el 100% de la pantalla se ve obligado a tomar ese, debes sacarlo

Comment: en la consola veo que dentro del body marca un margin de 8px, pero dentro del codigo no me doy cuenta donde esta ese margin

Comment: Ese es todo mi codigo, no me estaba dejando subirlo la página

Comment: Hola @user206022. He hecho un pequeño análisis al código que has compartido y el problema se encuentra en `width: 100vw;` y eso significa que cuando lo establece a `100vw` lo está estableciendo al`100%` del `viewport`, y el `viewport` incluye también el espacio que ocupa de la barra de desplazamiento vertical. Al quitarlo se resuelve.

Answer (score 4):

Probablemente porque lo tienes dentro de un contenedor u otro elemento que limita su tamaño.
Te muestro un ejemplo válido de cómo hacerlo sin el css extra que veo en tu código, utilizando Bootstrap:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    
        <!-- Bootstrap 4.5 css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <div class="container">
    
           tu código 
    
        </div><!--//container-->
    
        <footer class="fixed-bottom bg-secondary">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h6>XREF</h6>
                </div><!--//col-->
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p><i class="far fa-envelope-open"></i> xrefarquitectura@gmail.com</p>
                 </div><!--//col-->
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <p><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i> 098 436 244</p>
                </div><!--//col-->
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <p><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i> Xref</p>
                </div><!--//col-->
              </div><!--//row-->
              <hr id="line-footer">
              <div class="row">
                <div id="" class="col-md-3 ">
                  <p style="color: #ddd;"> &copy; XREF 2020</p>
                </div><!--//col-->
              </div><!--//row-->
            </div><!--//container fluid-->
        </footer>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

> Como puedes ver, también sustituí el `div` con id footer por una etiqueta `<footer>` que es la forma correcta y purista de crear este elemento en html.

Comment: No entiendo estas respuestas que dicen "probablemente algo está mal" y como solución ofrecen un snippet de la documentación oficial que fácilmente se puede incluir en un comentario. He visto varias ya y parece que son aceptadas por la comunidad.

Comment: La respuesta que di no fue sacada de ningún sitio, el ejemplo que cito es el código en su pregunta modificado para que funcione y sea correcto, por ejemplo no se suele hacer un footer en un div ya que existe la etiqueta footer para eso.

Comment: Claro, con la edición se entiende mejor tu punto

Answer (score 0):

Intente darle una posición absoluta y lo pones en `left -0.5%`.

Ejemplo:

```
position:absolute;
left:-0.5%;
```

Comment: De esta lo pude solucionar y queda reresponsive. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si tienes razon.

Comment: Y lograste tu objetivo.